# How to implement a draggable scrubber like Podcast app when VoiceOver is running?

Tags: ios, voiceover, uiaccessibility

Apple's Podcast app has an interesting feature available when VoiceOver is running.

When a user double taps and holds the scrubber, dragging left or right adjusts the scrubber position .

How is this done? I've made my attempts at allowing direct interaction with the scrubber via `UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction` , but you lose the ability to drag and scrub to a position if your finger goes outside of the scrubber's bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to not set it to `UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction`, but   `UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable`. This also allows an accessibility user to swipe up and down to adjust the scrubber.